# Load coco keypoints dataset in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow2.0, keypoint

How can I load coco keypoints dataset (image and keypoint annotations) in tensorflow using `tf.data.Dataset`?

There's a coco `Dataset` in tensorflow but it's only for object detection.

Regards.

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to load COCO dataset in tensorflow?